# Inconsistent Response of two different startActivityForResult From An AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have a `class` that extends `AppCompatActivity`.  Within this activity I do two different calls to two `startActivityForResult` methods which are hooked to two button listeners.  The first one calls a camera intent like so:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

and the second one calls another `AppCompatActivity` which holds a Google Map to wit:

```
Intent getLatLongIntent = new Intent(Form.this, MapsLatLongActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(getLatLongIntent, LATLONG_REQUEST);
```

The first `startActivityForResult` works fine and I can manipulate the response from the camera intent in the `onActivityResult` method.  What is puzzling is that the same `onActivityResult` does not get triggered when I close the child activity of the second call using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("brdgHouseLat", latitude);
intent.putExtra("brdgHouseLong", longitude);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Below is my code for the `onActivityResult` method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        himgres.setImageBitmap(photo);
    } else if (requestCode == LATLONG_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        latitude = data.getDoubleExtra("brdgHouseLat", 0);
        longitude = data.getDoubleExtra("brdgHouseLong", 0);
        Log.v(TAG, "and form has a lat = " + latitude);
        Log.v(TAG, "and a long = " + longitude);
    }
}
```

Needless to say I have goggled for solutions on this and have checked into my manifest (I haven't set any flags); fragments (no fragments here), etc.

Am starting to think that maybe `SharedPreferences` will be a better option but am just puzzled of the inconsistency of the responses.  Any help will be appreciated

=========================================================================
Here are the three methods of the second activity relevant to this question:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    packLatLong();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            packLatLong();
        }
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
}

private void packLatLong() {
    if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
        Log.v(TAG, "packing this lat = " + latitude);
        Log.v(TAG, "packing this long = " + longitude);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("brdgHouseLat", latitude);
        intent.putExtra("brdgHouseLong", longitude);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Please note that pressing either the back button as well as the home button in the action bar triggers the `packLatLong` method

Comment: we need to see the complete code to verify the issue, specifically of Activity where you are creating intent for `brdgHouseLat`

Comment: Thanks @Pavneet_Singh but I have tried to include all relevant codes for this case.  Please let me know what more codes are needed for me to be more clear.

Comment: of Activity where you are doing `intent.putExtra("brdgHouseLat", latitude);`

Comment: Oh, I call this under a refactored method.  Here:      private void packLatLong() {
        if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) {
            Log.v(TAG, "packing this lat = " + latitude);
            Log.v(TAG, "packing this long = " + longitude);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("brdgHouseLat", latitude);
            intent.putExtra("brdgHouseLong", longitude);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry can't seem to format that one in the comment... But yeah its a method that I call somewhere.  And I made sure that it gets called too (those are what the logs are for).

Comment: you need to post the complete code of activity by editing your post

Comment: Hi @Pavneet_Singh thanks for the help I have added 3 more methods that are relevant to this question.  The complete code for the activity contains other methods that I think has nothing to do with the inconsistent responses of onActivityResult.

Comment: are you pressing the home button go back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158291/discussion-between-marka-a-and-pavneet-singh).

Comment: if (requestCode == LATLONG_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)...  You may be check this condition resultcode == Ok.

Comment: That's not it at all @MohamedMohaideenAH as the onActivityResult itself is not triggered.  All other conditions following have no effect.

Comment: If onActivityResult not triggerred.. Check this condition are true.                   if (latitude != 0 && longitude != 0) { in second activity.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem with some hints from @Pavneet_Singh:

Here is the solution:

In the method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    packLatLong();
}
```

remove the call to super as it always returns a RESULT_CANCEL even if you set it to RESULT_OK.

This answer helped me on this -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241952/1637525.

I also changed

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

to

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```