# activity not sending result when pressing back button

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am using following code to start my activity

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddReceipt.class);

                startActivityForResult(myIntent, RECEIPT_ADDED);
            }
```

Now i want to get arrays from addreceipt class or data from my child activity

```
public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
             {
                 if (requestCode == RECEIPT_ADDED)
                 {
                     String abc = "abs";
                 }
             }

         }
```

when calling this function, it returns data as null and result code as 0. How can i get my data from my child activity.

BesT Regards

Comment: Did you look also at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679250/setresult-does-not-work-when-back-button-pressed

Comment: Please post your AddReceipt class or where you call Activity.setResult().

Comment: Thanks fyr. that did it. But how can i add my arraylist into that intent value. putextra has no type for an ArrayList

Comment: you have to put it as `putExtra(String name, Serializable value)` since ArrayList is implementing the `Serializable` interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data from child activity to parent activity use the following code:

```
Intent intent= childActivity.getIntent();
intent.putExtra("key","value");  
childActivity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
childActivity.finish();
```

if value is an list of object use Serializable .

Now if you press back button , `onActivityResult` method of parent class will be called and you will get `RESULT_CANCEL`.

Answer (score 1):

To get results from a sub-activity you need to call the [setResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) method inside your sub-activity, passing the result code and possibly any amount of data inside an `Intent` object. Then you can catch this `Intent` in the `onActivityResult()` of your main activity. Hope this helps.