# Wrong requestCode in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I'm starting a new Activity from my Fragment with

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and want to handle the result in the Fragment's parent Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult, requestCode: " + requestCode + ", resultCode: " + resultCode);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        // bla bla bla
    }
}
```

The problem is that I never got the `requestCode` I've just posted to `startActivityForResult()`.

I got something like `0x40001`, `0x20001` etc. with a random higher bit set. The docs don't say anything about this. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [onActivityResult not being called in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 919, accepted):

You are calling `startActivityForResult()` from your `Fragment`. When you do this, the `requestCode` is changed by the `Activity` that owns the `Fragment`.

If you want to get the correct `resultCode` in your activity try this:

Change:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

To:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Result do delivered to activity and I want it to be delivered there it's just has wrong requestCode

Comment: Because it should decide which fragment will deliver the result to .  So  when The Fragment call StartActivityForResult. the requestCode will be changed by the Activity, so it will know how to deliver the result to which fragment.   if you really want to get the result in the Activiy. just call getActivity().startActivityForResult().

Comment: Great answer.  Also, I'm not 100% but it appears that this may be a bug with the support package only:

[https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40537](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40537)

Comment: Just a note: if you use `startActivityForResult` in a fragment and expect the result from `onActivityResult` in that fragment, just make sure you call `super.onActivityResult` in the host activity (in case you override that method there). This is because the activity's `onActivityResult` seems to call the fragment's `onActivityResult`. Also, note that the request code, when it travels through the activity's `onActivityResult`, is altered as explained in the link that Dimanoid posted in his answer below. You might not need to know that but you never know...

Comment: I've raised it with the Android Team as it's either an error in the documentation or a bug in the implementation: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78260

Comment: @ChangweiYao ok! so, basically the Activity acts as a NAT.

Comment: "the requestCode is changed by the Activity that owns the Fragment" - Gotta love the Android design...

Comment: Such an important information, that you can't find anywhere clear in the docs. Gotta love the android design designed to make your life a hell.

Comment: You also can call `super.onActivityResult(arg1,arg2,arg3)` before call `fragment.onActivityResult(arg1,arg2,arg3)` in your FragementActivity

Comment: when i am calling getActivity().startActivityResult() ->request code is came
but not calling onActivityResult() in fragment,only calling activity method

Answer (score 45):

The request code is not wrong. When using v4 support library fragments, fragment index is encoded in the top 16 bits of the request code and your request code is in the bottom 16 bits. The fragment index is later used to find the correct fragment to deliver the result.

Hence for Activities started form fragment object, handle onActivityResult requestCode like below:

```
originalRequestCode = changedRequestCode - (indexOfFragment << 16)
      6             =      196614        -       (3 << 16)
```

Comment: Great info that explains the exact cause to this issue

Comment: quick question: what is indexOfFragment?

Comment: indexOfFragment is the index that the getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments () produces

Comment: Morale: Don't mix activity/fragment startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult(). When started from an activity, process the result in the activity. When started from a fragment, process the result in the fragment.

Answer (score 39):

**Easier:**

**Java**:
`int unmaskedRequestCode = requestCode & 0x0000ffff`

**Kotlin**:
`val unmaskedRequestCode = requestCode and 0x0000ffff`

Check for the lower 16 bits, just unmask it doing a logical AND with the upper 16 bits zeroed

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    final int unmaskedRequestCode = requestCode & 0x0000ffff

    if(unmaskedRequestCode == ORIGINAL_REQUEST_CODE){
      //Do stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why it not give the original request code?

Comment: Cause the requestCode is changed by the Activity that owns the Fragment. See Ashlesha Sharma answer

Comment: thank you, this is the answer I was looking for. I dont see why Android shouldnt return the original request code though.

Comment: This was immensely helpful for me today and actually explains the problem really nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you are providing constant make it public and then use in `startActivityResult`

example:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE =1;
getActivity().startActivityForresult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also define
`super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)`
in `Activity` (if you override`onActivityResult`)
at this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        ...

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

and call `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` inside your `Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

in Fragment

```
  getActivity().startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

in Main Activity:

```
if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {    
     //what ever you want to do
            }
```