# startActivityForResult() vs getActivity().startActivityForResult() in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, startactivityforresult

What the differences between `startActivityForResult()` vs `getActivity().startActivityForResult()` in Android Fragment? And what is the behaviour differences in `onActivityForResult()` when called in Fragment?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) and https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Don't you know that there is a documentation for Android development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()` must handle it from the `fragment`'s `onActivityForResult()`

`getActivity().startActivityForResult()` must handle it from the `activity`'s `onActivityForResult()`

**Basically:**

If you're on a `fragment` and you want to handle the result on the `fragment`, use `onActivityForResult()`, otherwise if you want to handle it from the `activity` of the fragment, use `getActivity.startActivityForResult()`

Answer (score 2):

**startActivityForResult** from fragment call **startActivityForResult** of its container Activity.
So for Fragment:-

> Call startActivityForResult(Intent, int) from the fragment's containing Activity.

Whereas when you use it in fragment directly some certain changes can be made on request code.And you will get modified request code in onActivityresult(), Cause i have faced some problem with modified request code recently . You can have a look into [This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564474/wrong-requestcode-in-onactivityresult).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `startActivityForResult()` inside Activity and `getActivity().startActivityForResult()` inside a Fragment.

Inshort, to get the Context of Activity we are preceeding it with `getActiviy()`.

Instead, we can Call particular Fragment's onActivityResult() as below from Actiivty.:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

If we put it to more details then,

If You will call `startActivityForResult()` from your Fragment,the requestCode will be changed by the Activity that owns the Fragment.

So, If you want to get the correct resultCode in your activity you can try as below :

**DO NOT USE :** (in such case):

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

**USE :**

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Hope it helps..!

Comment: actually I used `startActivityForResult()` in fragment without using `getActivity()`. That's why I ask the behaviour differences.

Comment: See @j.elmer There is no such difference among it. But, A little bit difference is we can use getActivity().startActivityForResult() only in fragment in order to get Context of Activity.

Comment: The whole point of a separate `startActivityForResult` method in Fragment is to avoid the need to go through all the Fragments in the Activity's onActivityResult. That's exactly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Go through All Fragment's ?? Will you please explain it little more ?

Answer (score 0):

No difference at all...
But A little bit difference is getActivity().startActivityForResult() can only call from a fragment :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a call with reference to `Activity`, since `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` is method specified in `Activity`.

So, if you call from `YourActivity`, it already has a reference of `Activity` like:

```
YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity (which is subclass of `Activity`)
```

But if you are calling it from `YourFragment` you need to specify `Activity` reference, which in this case will be the Activity containing `YourFragment`; hence we use `getActivity()` and then trigger `startActivityForResult()`

Answer (score 0):

"startActivityForResult()" works on Activity classes.
when you are in Activity class, you can directly use this method.
when you are in fragment, because fragment creates on Activity, you should first get the activity that fragment based on it. means:

```
//in fragment class:
Activity activity = this.getActivity();
```

now you have the activity and i said, you can use "startActivityForResult()" on activity that you get from fragment.

```
activity.startActivityForResult();
```

hope helps.