# Fragment of Fragment starting Activity for result Issue

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I have `ParentActivity` containing **3 fragments** attached to its `ViewPagerAdapter`. Then one of these fragments has **2 other fragments** (there are 2 buttons switching between those fragments inside this fragment).

When I create intent with `startActivityForResult(newIntent, 201)` inside one of these 2 (sub)fragments, as I finish up that started activity by `finish()`, inside `ParentActivity`s, `onActivityResult()` will return `requestCode 65737`. What's wrong with it?

SubFragment

```
addAddressButton.setOnClickListener {
            val addressCreateActivityIntent = Intent(context, AddressCreationActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(addressCreateActivityIntent, 201)
        }
```

ParentActivity

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        //addAddressActivity
        if (requestCode == 201){
            if (((pagerAdapter!!.getItem(1)) as OrderCartPaymentFragment).view != null){
                createLog("DeliveryAddress ", "RefreshingAddressData -> OrderCart")
                ((pagerAdapter!!.getItem(1)) as OrderCartPaymentFragment).refreshDeliveryFragmentData()
            }
        }
    }
```

That means, onActivityResult() will call refresh inside fragment which is parent fragment of that subfragment. And as chain reaction refreshDeliveryFragment() will call one of those 2 subfragments to refresh their recyclerview data.

Comment: Can you post the code of your fragment and the ParentActivity please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10564488/9313652

you should just change:

`startActivityForResult(newIntent, 201)`

to:

`getActivity().startActivityForResult(newIntent, 201)`