# Incorrect request code in OnActivityResult() Result after updating AppCompat Version

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-appcompat, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

My app uses the `startActivityForResult` pattern.  To account for the fact that I am calling `startActivityForResult` from a fragment [I unmask the request code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42702301/8890753).

**MyFragment.java**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    int unmaskedRequestCode = requestCode & 0x0000ffff;

    if (unmaskedRequestCode == 1) {
        success();
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that this code works perfectly fine when my `build.gradle` used

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

However,  when I upgraded to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

I started getting requestCodes that seemed random.  In my testing it looked like you could work around this by instead calling `startActivityForResult` from the parent `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`. However,  I would prefer to understand the issue better before I start changing code to account for this new version.

**What changed in appcompat that causes the newer version to give different request codes than before?**

Comment: You may want to consider using the new pattern that [replaces startActivityForResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) - then you don't have to deal with request/response codes at all.

Comment: ^That's actually what's causing the random request codes in the `Activity`, too, 'cause recent versions are rerouting the applicable `Fragment` methods through that new `Activity` result registry mechanism, which generates its own codes. Your actual request code is being tracked internally, but I think the only place it's accessible is in the `Fragment`, since `FragmentManager` is who's ultimately tracking the request info and handling the `onActivityResult()` dispatch to the `Fragment`s.