# Android Intent is null

Tags: android, android-intent

I start an application with this code:

```
Intent hasApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("appName.app");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
dataId = response.getdataId();
intent.setData(Uri.parse("appName:?pid=" + dataId + "&action=returntoapp"));
startActivityForResult(intent, Globals.DATA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And i close the opened application with this code:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

But when the first app called the onActivityResult() method I got the same requestCode, but the intent is null, and the resultCode is ACTIVITY_CANCELED.

I don't understand why.

Comment: where is onActivityResult ?

Comment: in the same Activity where i started the other application

Comment: You need to call `setResult()` from some positive user action (e.g., tapping on a `ListView` row), not from someplace like `onPause()`.

Comment: CommonsWare i called the setResult() you can see this in my question, and i dont close the application in onPause(), i close this after some calculate and network communications.

Comment: `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)`, where is the Intent ?

Comment: as i know if i dont want to send back extras to the first app or activity i dont need to write the Intent intent = new Intent() or getIntent()

Comment: I just want send back the status, nothing else

Comment: and how is it possible, that the requestCode is the same what i want to get, but the resultCode not, and the intent is null?

Comment: Did you check that you really call setResult(RESULT_OK)?

Comment: The intent is null because you do not set one. The request code is the same as you are returning to the caller. I guess you don't really call success.

Comment: ofcourse i debugged it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setResult does not work when BACK button pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679250/setresult-does-not-work-when-back-button-pressed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String packageName = "com.example.app"

public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            if (i == null) {
                return false;

            }
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            context.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```